# Optimal key for MySQL / InnoDB table with multi-part WHERE

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, indexing

Given a (simplified) table

```
CREATE TABLE  `transactions` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CREATION_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS_IND` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMPANY_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AMOUNT` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FKE7E81F1ED170D4C9` (`COMPANY_ID`),
  KEY `RPTIDX_CREATION_DT` (`CREATION_DT`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5241784 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and a common, relatively expensive query

```
UPDATE transactions
SET STATUS_IND = 5
WHERE
COMPANY_ID = ?
 and (STATUS_IND = 3 or STATUS_IND = 7)
 and CREATION_DT >= ? and CREATION_DT <= ?
```

I'm trying to determine if there is a better index strategy.  Reads will most commonly

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE COMPANY_ID=? ORDER BY CREATION_DT
```

`COMPANY_ID` is fairly selective (we have hundreds of companies in the table, growing quickly).  `STATUS_IND` is not very selective (there are 5 common statuses and a few less common ones), and it's value frequently changes (`COMPANY_ID` and `CREATION_DT` never change for a given row).  `CREATION_DT` is fairly selective and getting more selective over time as we add more transactions to the system.

My initial thought is to replace the two existing keys with a compound key containing either `COMPANY_ID+CREATION_DT` or `COMPANY_ID+STATUS_IND+CREATION_DT`.  Alternatively, possibly `COMPANY_ID+CREATION_DT+STATUS_IND` and change the order in the Update's WHERE clause?

Also, is there a good reference that explains how InnoDB uses secondary compound indexes?

Comment: Have you tried EXPLAIN on your SQL queries? Sometimes it helps diagnose where bottlenecks may occur.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, EXPLAIN only works for SELECT queries, not updates.  If I transform the UPDATE to a similar SELECT, is the EXPLAIN SELECT useful for optimizing the original UPDATE?

Comment: EXPLAIN for a SELECT variant of the UPDATE only tells me which keys are available and which is used.  It does not recommend a better key.

Comment: EXPLAIN helps determines which fields may involved the use of keys. I think you could write a small benchmark and see for yourself which solution is the best. Do you have lot of entries you can test performances with?

Comment: Yes, we have lots and lots of entities :-)  It takes around 30 minutes to recreate the index on a mirror DB each time I try another combination, and there are many other tables that probably face similar issues, so I'm really trying to get a more fundamental grasp of how indexing and index tuning works on MySQL.

Comment: Re: Query update - the IN clause is the only improvement.  BETWEEN is inclusive, so it is equivalent.

Comment: Are you saying that IN is processed differently than a series of equivalent OR statements?  That would surprise me, since if one is more efficient than the other, the parser should internally rewrite it.  Not saying it isn't so, just that it would surprise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My initial thought is to replace the two existing keys with a compound key...

This a better approach than individual keys.
Compound/covering index/key executes from left to right, meaning that the order of the list is important as it is read left to right.  For example, if you define the index as: `COMPANY_ID`, `CREATION_DT`, `STATUS_IND`, the following combinations can trigger the use of the index:

1. `COMPANY_ID`
2. `COMPANY_ID`, `CREATION_DT`
3. `COMPANY_ID`, `CREATION_DT`, `STATUS_IND`

So if you only had `CREATION_DT`, or `CREATION_DT`, `STATUS_IND` - the index would not be used.

The order doesn't matter in the WHERE clause - just as long as the columns are referenced.

Keep in mind too that all indexes for a MyISAM table can only sum up to 1000 bytes long (767 bytes for InnoDB tables), [as designed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/indexes.html).

---

BTW: I rewrote your UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE transactions
   SET STATUS_IND = 5
 WHERE COMPANY_ID = ?
   AND STATUS_IND IN (3, 7)
   AND CREATION_DT BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference between the original update and the way you rewrote it, or is it an issue of being more human-readable?  The original query was generated by Hibernate and I'm not sure how easy it is to make these types of changes.